# Override contextPath on solr start from command line

Tags: solr, jetty, solr5

Is it possible to override jetty "contextPath" property when starting Solr 5 using command line arguments? 
I want something like

```
bin/solr -p 8983 -s "example/techproducts/solr" -a "-DcontextPath=/s"
```

So that the base url will be http://localhost:8983/s

To be precise, I want to override exactly contextPath property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your question is about the context path of solr as jetty webapp.

Instead of

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/
```

you want to access solr via

```
http://localhost:8983/s/
```

imho this is not possible without changing a configuration file.

Be aware that with zookeeper and solrCloud there is the parameter [hostContext](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Parameter+Reference) in [solr.xml](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/solr/Format+of+solr.xml#Formatofsolr.xml-The%3Csolrcloud%3Eelement) and you can use system properties in solr.xml like [hostContext](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCloud#SolrCloud_Instance_Params).

Without zookeeper but with changing

```
server\contexts\solr-jetty-context.xml
```

you will get what you want:

change from

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath"><Property name="hostContext" default="/solr"/></Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.base"/>/solr-webapp/webapp</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base"/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

to this:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE Configure PUBLIC "-//Jetty//Configure//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/jetty/configure_9_0.dtd">
<Configure class="org.eclipse.jetty.webapp.WebAppContext">
  <Set name="contextPath"><SystemProperty name="hostContext" default="/solr"/></Set>
  <Set name="war"><Property name="jetty.base"/>/solr-webapp/webapp</Set>
  <Set name="defaultsDescriptor"><Property name="jetty.base"/>/etc/webdefault.xml</Set>
  <Set name="extractWAR">false</Set>
</Configure>
```

Now you can start with

```
solr start -a "-DhostContext=/s"
```