# How to change hostContext property in Solr 5

Tags: search, indexing, solr, nosql

I am playing with Solr 5.3.1 and trying to change `hostContext` property from default value of `solr`, but can't seem to find how to do it.

It looks like I can change a `hostPort` like this:

```
bin/solr start -p 8984
```

And I would expect smth like this for the `hostContext` property, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

It seems that `SolrCloud` tag in `solr.xml` has a parameter `hostContext`, but I am not using cloud, and I do not intend to use it. I have no intention to use `SolrCloud` tag whatsoever. Does anybody know how to change `hostContext` property for normal non-cloud cores?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Override contextPath on solr start from command line](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34772611/override-contextpath-on-solr-start-from-command-line)

Answer (score 0):

The SolrCloud config doesn't actually change the URL path that Solr will use.  It changes what SolrCloud reports when it registers with Zookeeper, which must match what the container (usually Jetty) actually uses.  If you are thinking that it's insane that these are configured separately, then you're right -- which is why we are trying to make Solr into a standalone application.

https://wiki.apache.org/solr/WhyNoWar

The actual URL path for Solr 5.x is configured in server/contexts/solr-jetty-context.xml -- it's a config for Jetty, not Solr.

I do have to ask why you want to change the context, as this seems like it might be an XY problem.

http://people.apache.org/~hossman/#xyproblem

If the reason you want to change the context is so that you can have multiple instances on different URL paths ... you probably need to rethink what you are doing.  Running multiple instances is not recommended, especially if they are in the same JVM.  There *are* some very specific use cases where running multiple Solr JVMs might be required, but for those instances, there is no reason to change the context, because each one will be using a different port.